# Why can typescript infer non-null types using double negation but not with the boolean constructor?

Tags: typescript, casting, type-inference

The example below illustrates the fact that typescript can infer that `someVal` is not null when casting it to a boolean using double negation (`!!`), but not when casting it (more explicitly) using the Boolean constructor. I personally prefer using the Boolean constructor to cast values, but ran into this problem. Could someone tell me why this happens?

```js
const someVal: number | null = null

if (!!someVal) {
    const res = someVal + 2; // ok
}
if (Boolean(someVal)) {
    const res = someVal + 2; // Object is possibly 'null'.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16655) to make `Boolean` a type guard, but it just has not been implemented yet (or more accurately it was implemented and caused other issues, so it was reverted)

If you are ok with the break outlined in the issue, you can add it yourself:

```
const someVal: number | null = null

interface BooleanConstructor {
  <T>(value?: T): value is Exclude<T, false | null | undefined | '' | 0>;
}

if (Boolean(someVal)) {
    const res = someVal + 2; // Ok now
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=16&pln=4&pc=3#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmA1AhgGwFwzAVwQCMkAnGAH1zwwxgF4qaBYAKFYEswpSAzNYJDABCIEBiRowAYXDQSeYFBBkA3qxgwAPABUAfAAoAbpjxIA-Dm0BKHMYymY7CDACiAD2D2AJkh0AaGD4MCEFKfBoKGDwwHx5OJC9IgHIkyIAGXQBuVgBfVg4eGH0AQmL4ZHQMKxg1Fg0NUEhYEiRnBnLUTBgAahgAJkyYAHohmBAAa1yCopExCTB9Dsqratr6mEboGBa2uERO2l6B4dGAeUIAKyRFR2cABxAICHZCDABPGCTwjCSAOlygA)